# Retrieve DelegateGroups and accounts associated with those groups from Salesforce

Tags: java, soap, salesforce

I am trying to bring in a set of groups called: DelegateGroup - Salesforce defines it as follows:  [DelegatedGroups](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_delegategroup.htm)

The meta data supplied shows the following:

```
   <xsd:complexType name="DelegateGroup">
    <xsd:complexContent>
     <xsd:extension base="tns:Metadata">
      <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="customObjects" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>
       <xsd:element name="groups" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>
       <xsd:element name="label" type="xsd:string"/>
       <xsd:element name="loginAccess" type="xsd:boolean"/>
       <xsd:element name="permissionSets" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>
       <xsd:element name="profiles" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>
       <xsd:element name="roles" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

However this wasn't introduced until v36 so I went in and upgraded the Soap stubs to v46 - I am able to pull data from Salesforce, but I haven't figured out how to retrieve the DelegateGroup  or how the accounts are associated with the delegategroup.

Note: The reason for the java tag is because I am coding this in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Delegated Administrators can't be retrieved/deployed via metadata api.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm) I think at best you'll get group names/permissions but not who's actually assigned. We know `DelegateGroup` and `DelegateGroupMember` objects exist (you can find them in online lists of obscure Salesforce object id prefixes) but they aren't exposed via API. See also https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129/querying-delegated-administrators

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, if they aren't exposed via the API than that would explain why I can't pull them in my requests. It blows my mind that you would have an API and have a data that you can extract via the calls? Why have the API? Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to add the following which is directly from Salesforce:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm  - this URL contains all the metatypes that are not retrievable via the API - I would paste them here to follow up with your answer above - but there are too many... so the URL will have to suffice.

Comment: But that's the link in my first sentence? :) I mean I could paste them all to answer in case the documentation changes and link goes dead... unlikely? And as you say, they're too many. Pretty much every release makes something new deployable so content would get outdated...